# Convert incoming XML to key pair XML using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, key-value

```
Can you please help me convert incoming XML to key value XML using groovy for eg?
```

Please refer to the example below for conversion. The example contains two fields only but in actual may contain many fields

```
<root>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Major</LastName>
</root>


to 

<root>
    <row>
        <Key>FirstName</Key>
        <Value>John</Value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Key>LastName</Key>
        <Value>Major</Value>
    </row>
</root>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you're after.

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlSlurper
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def startingXmlTxt =
'''<root>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Major</LastName>
</root>'''

def startingXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(startingXmlTxt)

def sw = new StringWriter()
def bldr = new MarkupBuilder(sw)

bldr.root {
    startingXml.'*'.each { aRt ->
        row {
            Key(aRt.name())
            Value(aRt.text())
        }
    }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize( new XmlSlurper().parseText( sw.toString() ) )
```

And back...

```
startingXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(sw.toString())
sw = new StringWriter()
bldr = new MarkupBuilder(sw)

bldr.root {
    startingXml.'*'.each{ aRt ->
        "${aRt.Key}"( aRt.Value )
    }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize( new XmlSlurper().parseText( sw.toString() ) )
```

Comment: Can you please help to convert XML to other way round for eg root>
    <row>
        <Key>FirstName</Key>
        <Value>John</Value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Key>LastName</Key>
        <Value>Major</Value>
    </row>
</root> to <root>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Major</LastName>
</root>

Comment: Answer updated with reversal